# PHP Javascript / AJAX Forms

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

I am attempting to code a "stream" where users can input a status about themselves.

I have got this working, but I would like it so that you do not have to reload the page to see your new status.

I know that you would need to use Ajax to do something like this, but the problem is that I do not know anything about Javascript and Ajax.

The code I have is:

```
if(isset($_POST['send-stream'])){
    dbquery("INSERT INTO friend_stream (userid,type,timestamp,status) VALUES ('".USER_ID."','1',current_timestamp(),'".clean($_POST['status'])."')");
    header("Location: ".WWW."/me");



<div class="new-stream">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="status" value="What's Up?" maxlength="150" onclick="this.value='';" />
        <input type="submit" name="send-stream" value="Share" />
    </form>
</div>
```

When they submit their status, I would also like it that the div (#friend-stream) automatically updates too.

Anyone that knows how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this question is too non-specific.  there are plenty of free resources for learning basic javascript and ajax.  i recommend using a library such as jquery (http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way is to start reading something about ajax and JS.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

if you would use jQuery, you would do something like this

```
$('#submitStatusButton').click(function(){
   var status = $('#statusId').val();
   if (.. something to validate that status is valid and not the same){
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "yourFileForUpdating.php",
          data: {
             status: status,
             // may be some other params
          }
      }).done(function( msg ) {
          // update your status
      });
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from AJAX I suggest doing it with WebSockets if you want to do it at real-time.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket